# What the Chinese, Japanese, and Korean characters are in Unicode

Tags: unicode, cjk

From [what](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366068/whats-the-complete-range-for-chinese-characters-in-unicode) I've [gathered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33395130/unicode-characters-necessary-for-japanese-korean-and-chinese):

> Hiragana is U+3040 to U+309F
>
> Katakana is U+30A0 to U+30FF.
>
> U+4E00..U+9FFF is part of the complete [Chinese] set, but not all.
>
> The exact ranges for Chinese characters (except the extensions) are [\u2E80-\u2FD5\u3190-\u319f\u3400-\u4DBF\u4E00-\u9FCC\uF900-\uFAAD].
>
> CJK (for Chinese, Japanese, Korean) encompasses all characters for the Chinese Hànzì, the Japanese Kanji and the Korean Hanja. (So they are all mixed).

The linked answers don't fully explain where everything is. Wondering if there is a clear answer to this so I don't have to go through each character one-by-one.

Comment: This is not the kind of problem you ever want to have to solve, it is quite unclear why you'd need to.  Both Japanese and Korean [have adopted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_characters#Adaptation_to_other_languages) Chinese glyphs in their script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so I don't have to go through each character one-by-one.

You're supposed to examine the [properties](http://p3rl.org/uniprops). This is for Unicode 12.1.

Script_Extensions: Han (89513 characters)

```
U+02E80…U+02E99
U+02E9B…U+02EF3
U+02F00…U+02FD5
U+03001…U+03003
U+03005…U+03011
U+03013…U+0301F
U+03021…U+0302D
U+03030
U+03037…U+0303F
U+030FB
U+03190…U+0319F
U+031C0…U+031E3
U+03220…U+03247
U+03280…U+032B0
U+032C0…U+032CB
U+032FF
U+03358…U+03370
U+0337B…U+0337F
U+033E0…U+033FE
U+03400…U+04DB5
U+04E00…U+09FEF
U+0F900…U+0FA6D
U+0FA70…U+0FAD9
U+0FE45…U+0FE46
U+0FF61…U+0FF65
U+1D360…U+1D371
U+1F250…U+1F251
U+20000…U+2A6D6
U+2A700…U+2B734
U+2B740…U+2B81D
U+2B820…U+2CEA1
U+2CEB0…U+2EBE0
U+2F800…U+2FA1D
```

Script_Extensions: Hangul (11775 characters)

```
U+01100…U+011FF
U+03001…U+03003
U+03008…U+03011
U+03013…U+0301F
U+0302E…U+03030
U+03037
U+030FB
U+03131…U+0318E
U+03200…U+0321E
U+03260…U+0327E
U+0A960…U+0A97C
U+0AC00…U+0D7A3
U+0D7B0…U+0D7C6
U+0D7CB…U+0D7FB
U+0FE45…U+0FE46
U+0FF61…U+0FF65
U+0FFA0…U+0FFBE
U+0FFC2…U+0FFC7
U+0FFCA…U+0FFCF
U+0FFD2…U+0FFD7
U+0FFDA…U+0FFDC
```

Script_Extensions: Hiragana (431 characters)

```
U+03001…U+03003
U+03008…U+03011
U+03013…U+0301F
U+03030…U+03035
U+03037
U+0303C…U+0303D
U+03041…U+03096
U+03099…U+030A0
U+030FB…U+030FC
U+0FE45…U+0FE46
U+0FF61…U+0FF65
U+0FF70
U+0FF9E…U+0FF9F
U+1B001…U+1B11E
U+1B150…U+1B152
U+1F200
```

Script_Extensions: Katakana (356 characters)

```
U+03001…U+03003
U+03008…U+03011
U+03013…U+0301F
U+03030…U+03035
U+03037
U+0303C…U+0303D
U+03099…U+0309C
U+030A0…U+030FF
U+031F0…U+031FF
U+032D0…U+032FE
U+03300…U+03357
U+0FE45…U+0FE46
U+0FF61…U+0FF9F
U+1B000
U+1B164…U+1B167
```

Comment: Why is the OP supposed to go to Perl documentation first?  The question has zero reference to Perl.

Answer (score 2):

This is a sorted list containing anything that's used in Chinese, Japanese, Korean (and also some Vietnamese)

- U+1100..U+11FF: [Hangul Jamo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangul_Jamo_(Unicode_block))
- U+2E80..U+2EFF[CJK Radicals Supplement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Radicals_Supplement_(Unicode_block))
- U+2F00..U+2FDF: [Kangxi Radicals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kangxi_Radicals_(Unicode_block))
- U+3000..U+303F: [CJK Symbols and Punctuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Symbols_and_Punctuation) (may not be counted as characters, depending on what you want to do)
- U+3040..U+309F: [Hiragana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiragana_(Unicode_block))
- U+30A0..U+30FF: [Katakana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katakana_(Unicode_block))
- U+3100..U+312F: [Bopomofo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bopomofo_(Unicode_block))
- U+3130..U+318F: [Hangul Compatibility Jamo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangul_Compatibility_Jamo)
- U+3190..U+319F: [Kanbun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanbun_(Unicode_block))
- U+31A0..U+31BF: [Bopomofo Extended](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bopomofo_Extended)
- U+31C0..U+31EF: [CJK Strokes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Strokes_(Unicode_block))
- U+31F0..U+31FF: [Katakana Phonetic Extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katakana_Phonetic_Extensions)
- U+31F0..U+31FF: [Katakana Phonetic Extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katakana_Phonetic_Extensions)
- U+3200..U+32FF: [Enclosed CJK Letters and Months](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enclosed_CJK_Letters_and_Months)
- U+3300..U+33FF: [CJK Compatibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Compatibility)
- U+3400..U+4DBF: [CJK Unified Ideographs Extension A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Unified_Ideographs#CJK_Unified_Ideographs_Extension_A)
- U+4E00..U+9FEF: [CJK Unified Ideographs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Unified_Ideographs#CJK_Unified_Ideographs_blocks)
- U+A960..U+A97F: [Hangul Jamo Extended-A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangul_Jamo_Extended-A)
- U+AC00..U+D7A3: [Hangul Syllables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangul_Syllables)
- U+D7B0..U+D7FF: [Hangul Jamo Extended-B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangul_Jamo_Extended-B)
- U+F900..U+FAFF: [CJK Compatibility Ideographs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Unified_Ideographs#CJK_Compatibility_Ideographs)
- U+FE30..U+FE4F: [CJK Compatibility Forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Compatibility_Forms)
- U+FF00..U+FFEF: [Halfwidth and Fullwidth Forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halfwidth_and_fullwidth_forms_(Unicode_block)). But this also contains punctuation symbols and Latin alphabet. Real Katakana and Jamo characters are from U+FF66 to U+FFDD
- U+1B000..U+1B0FF: [Kana Supplement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kana_Supplement)
- U+1B100..U+1B12F: [Kana Extended-A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kana_Extended-A)
- U+1B130..U+1B16F: [Small Kana Extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_Kana_Extension)
- U+1F200..U+1F2FF: [Enclosed Ideographic Supplement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enclosed_Ideographic_Supplement)
- U+20000..U+2A6DF: [CJK Unified Ideographs Extension B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Unified_Ideographs#CJK_Unified_Ideographs_Extension_B)
- U+2A700..U+2B73F: [CJK Unified Ideographs Extension C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Unified_Ideographs#CJK_Unified_Ideographs_Extension_C)
- U+2B740..U+2B81F: [CJK Unified Ideographs Extension D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Unified_Ideographs#CJK_Unified_Ideographs_Extension_D)
- U+2B820..U+2CEAF: [CJK Unified Ideographs Extension E](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Unified_Ideographs#CJK_Unified_Ideographs_Extension_E)
- U+2CEB0..U+2EBEF: [CJK Unified Ideographs Extension F](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Unified_Ideographs#CJK_Unified_Ideographs_Extension_F)
- U+2F800..U+2FA1F: [CJK Compatibility Ideographs Supplement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Compatibility_Ideographs_Supplement)
- U+30000..U+3134F: [CJK Unified Ideographs Extension G](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Unified_Ideographs#CJK_Unified_Ideographs_Extension_G)